# What is the default sort order by Lucene Search in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

I'm using Sitecore 6.5 and wanted to know in what sort order lucene arrange the search results by default? Also can we change(replace) this default behavior with our custom sort logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Documents are sorted by *relevance* by default. You can sort by any field, here's the simple example (within the SearchContext):

```
var searchHits = new SearchHits(searchContext.Searcher.Search(query, new Sort("__created", true)));
var results = searchHits.FetchResults(0, 100);
```

Where "__created" is a field you want to sort by.

Comment: Is "relevance" a system field like "__created" ? I'm asking this because I want to know the name of actual field(s) which is(are) used by lucene while default sorting process?

Comment: No, "relevance" is a frequency of search term in the document, it is calculated using complex formulas in Lucene.